# System can't find python.exe even though it's added to path

Tags: python, windows, pip, path, system

I was using python fine last night, but this morning, any python command I try to run gives me this error

```
The system cannot find the file C:\Users\nickr\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe.
```

Even if I do this in a virtual environment, it gives me this error

```
Unable to create process using '"C:\Users\nickr\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe" C:/Users/nickr/Documents/assistApp/main.py'
```

I've set my path variable to the directory given in the error and still nothing, I've tried installing windows build tools and I've restarted my console. I even tried deleting and reinstalling python, and I made it set a path variable and it still doesn't work.

Comment: What is the output of `echo %PATH%`? Also try restarting system, just incase for the system PATH and files to re-load.

Comment: have you checked the file in error said? is the file there or no?

Comment: @AzharKhan `C:\Users\nickr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\; C:\Users\nickr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\; C:\Users\nickr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310; 
C:\Users\nickr\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe; C:\Users\nickr\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.10.exe;` I tried restarting my pc but unfortunately, no luck :(

Comment: @HenroSutrisnoTanjung python.exe is in fact in the directory the error states

Comment: Cleanup your `PATH`s. Where is your python installed? Set following env variables accordingly:
`set PYTHONPATH=<python installation folder>`
`set PATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%PYTHONPATH%\Lib;%PYTHONPATH%\DLLs;%PYTHONPATH%\Scripts;%PATH%`

Comment: I cleaned up the paths to only lead to one python directory (and ignoring everything that isn't relevant) , `C:\Users\nickr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310;` This is the same path that python is installed in, yet when I run any python command, it's still looking in `C:\Users\nickr\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem, the directory that the error gave was also in my path variables and so windows was constantly looking there, so I just deleted that path in my path variables so it didn't look there anymore and all of my python scripts are working